# Does a std::vector constructor not call object constructors for each element?

Tags: c++

My code resembles something along these lines.

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(int i) { printf("hello %d\n", i); }
    ~A() { printf("Goodbye\n"); }
}


std::vector(10, A(10));
```

I notice that hello prints out once.
It seems to imply that the vector only allocates space for the element 
but doesn't construct it.    How do I make it construct 10 A objects?

Comment: quite a few people frown upon using C style IO in C++ code (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.1)

Comment: it's only an example OK?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The object is constructed only once, as you pass it to std::vector. Then this object is copied 10 times. You have to do a printf in the copy constructor to see it.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        int i;
public:
        A(int d) : i(d) { cout << "create i=" << i << endl; }
        ~A() { cout << "destroy" << endl; }
        A(const A& d) : i(d.i) { cout << "copy i=" << d.i << endl; }
};

int main()
{
        vector<A> d(10,A(10));
}
```

Output:

```
create i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
copy i=10
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
```

Answer (score 3):

`A(10)` constructs a temporary object. Only once. The 10 elements of your vector are constructed via the ***copy-constructor***. So if you define a copy-constructor to print B you'll get 10 B's.

Answer (score 1):

Define copy constructor and you will be fine:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>


class A
{
    public:
        A(int i) { printf("hello %d\n", i); }
        ~A() { printf("Goodbye\n"); }
        A(const A&)
        {
            printf("copy constructing\n");
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector< A > a( 10, A(5) );
}
```

Comment: why #include <iostream> and <algorithm> but not use them and not include <stdio.h>?

Comment: @awoodland bad copy and paste

Comment: If you `#include <cstdio>`, you should use `std::printf`. If you want to use printf without the std::, use `#include <stdio.h>`.